# How to change string column sorting to decimal sorting in WPF Listview column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have another issue with sorting numbers which are actually string [varchar] from DB. In the WPF listview, the cell template is having a textbox.

When the data is loaded in the listview from the DB, the listview Salary column is binded to the salary column in the data table. Due to some other business logic, this salary column in the database table is varchar.

But when it is shown in the listview, salary is shown as "456.56" like floating or decimal numbers in the salary cell column in the listview. Since the underlying data source is the data table, Salary column is a varchar datatype !! So when sorting the listview salary column, it is not sorting the salary column exactly like numbers !!

Can I use an IComparer in this case ? If so, how ? any example is much helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just iterate through the data, either when you retrieve it, or in the view model before you display it and parse the data to the correct data type? Then you can let the `ListView` do the sorting:

```
foreach (YourDataType item in yourItemCollection)
{
    YourDisplayDataType displayItem = new YourDisplayDataType(item.Property1, 
        item.Property2, decimal.Parse(item.DecimalVarcharProperty));
}
```

Of course, if you do this, you'll need to ensure that the `decimal VARCHAR` values coming from the database *are* actually all decimal values. If not, you could do the above in two stages:

```
foreach (YourDataType item in yourItemCollection)
{
    decimal decimalValue = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(item.DecimalVarcharProperty, out decimalValue);
    YourDisplayDataType displayItem = new YourDisplayDataType(item.Property1, 
        item.Property2, decimalValue);
}
```

> Disclaimer: I can't check this in a compiler at present, so there *may* be an error... please let me know if that is the case and I will update the answer.